# Using BLE in RSL10 Evaluation and development kit

Tags: c, eclipse, arm, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am using ON semiconductor's RSL10 development kit and has an ARM cortex M3 processor.

I have flashed the sample code given by them i.e. peripheral server and central client. I am able to establish a connection but I am unable to send the data sent from the server and display it on the console. I am using C for programming in Eclipse IDE. I also want to read the `RSSI` register value.

Can anyone please tell how can it be done?

Comment: Do a console print. If you do have access to In-Circuit emulator, or JTAG debuggers you can watch the register value when run in debug mode.

Comment: Can you please give an example because when I use printf statement it throws an error when I build it even after including all the libraries.

Comment: Please post you print error.

Comment: c:/program files (x86)/on semiconductor/rsl10 sdk/arm_tools/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/6.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/thumb/v7-m\libg_nano.a(lib_a-isattyr.o): In function `_isatty_r':
isattyr.c:(.text._isatty_r+0xc): undefined reference to `_isatty'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [central_client.elf] Error 1

Comment: Is the library provided custom one? Check if `printf` is disabled or not part of or not supported by the library.

Comment: Eclipse is recognising the printf statement. Is it possible for you have a look into the code

Comment: Please paste your linker settings, and tool chain used. Eclipse recognition doesn't really means linker will find it.

Answer (score 1):

There are two steps:

1. `include <stdio.h>` in files you want to call printf from.
2. At the start of your application (main function in app.c, first call) add a call to the `function:  initialise_monitor_handles();`  To help the compiler, advance define it with an `extern void initialise_monitor_handles(void);`

This should get your printf to work.

Comment: 1) should have said to include stdio.h (perhaps the special characters around that caused the text to be deleted.)

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for reading RSSI value from central side, we have the sample code ble_central_client_scan.   If you are looking for print information in console, you can reference our sample project  “print_nvr_info”. This sample project can print information in console window.

Comment: Martin, welcome to Stack Overflow.  You'll need to link to your project referred to in "we have the sample code" for this answer to be of any use to anyone.